# Devolver una fila de datos en ASP.NET Core

Tags: json, asp.net-core, postman

Buenas a todos comunidad , quisiera ejecutar un store procedure con ado.net y que me retorne una fila de datos , pero solo logro que me devuelva solo un dato , que tengo que agregar para que me retorna una tabla y se almacene como json.¿Qué tengo que agregar?

Quiero que me retorne así pero en formato json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi código

```
[HttpGet("prueba/{celular}")]
        public ActionResult prueba(string celular)
        {
            var rpta = "";
            string consql = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=bdprueba;User ID=local;Password=******"; 
            using (SqlConnection bdSql = new SqlConnection(consql))
            {
                bdSql.Open();
                SqlCommand bdComando = new SqlCommand("sp_usuario", bdSql);
                bdComando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                bdComando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p_celular", celular));
                try
                {
                    var rdr = bdComando.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                    return Ok(rdr);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    rpta = e.Message.ToString();
                }
            }
            return Ok(rpta);
        }
```

solo me retorna el primer dato

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero tu SP esta creado para devolver una lista?, porque en tu imagen solo se ve una fila como resultado

Comment: @RamiroBarone solo regresa una fila, y quisiera que me regrese en formato json  , así como en la imagen de arriba una lista

Answer (score 0):

podrias usar forjson auto en tu consulta aqui en la doc de microsoft esta el ejemplo [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Format%20query%20results%20as%20JSON%2C%20or%20export%20data%20from%20SQL,the%20app%20to%20SQL%20Server.)

en cuanto a porque solo te regresa un campo debes tener un error en tu procedure

Answer (score 0):

creo que deberías de verificar tu store procedure!! pues es el el que decide que devolver!! pero otro lado allí te devuelve es una objeto que debería viajar en formato json sin necesidad de mas nada, ósea en ves de pasar tu repuesta a cadena de texto este debe de captar el valor dentro de un objeto!!

Comment: Esto parece más un comentario que una respuesta, en cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás comentar en la pregunta